# WPF XAML GUI designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, blend

I am developing a DESKTOP WPF application.

I have been writing all my XAML GUI elements manually, and its becoming way too complicated for me now.

I need a tool that I can use with VS2010 to help me design all my GUI elements.

I have been reading about Expression but its a little confusing as to what I should get.

From Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ES/expression) they talk only about VS2012. they also say that Expression Studio is discontinued.

What is the tool i should use to do the design that I need?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Pure XAML is the best way to go...

Comment: If you must have a GUI and can't afford Blend/Don't have VS 2012 you can try KaXaml, it's free and pretty good...

Comment: whats wrong with the VS2010 designer?

Comment: I would agree with @DeanK. The VS Designer is totally unreliable when you drag and drop controls onto it... they hardly ever seem to go where I want them to and they always get given unwanted properties set on them... I personally find it *much* quicker to just write the XAML manually.